# What does $\big(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}, \cdot\,, 1\big)$ represent?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, abelian-groups

What does $\big(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}, \cdot\,, 1\big)$ represent?

I found this in an introductory video on real analysis, under the heading "Axioms of reals".

Comment: More context would be useful.  Perhaps did it say: "$\big(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}, \cdot\,, 1\big)$ is an abelian group" ??

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},\cdot,1)$ is denoting the multiplicative group of real numbers: under the usual multiplication, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is a group, with identity element $1$.